# LibGDX Animation doesn't work with >6 frames

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I have a file called `spritesheet.png`, which has 7 frames of my sprite lined up side by side.

I am using this code:

```
TextureRegion[] reg = TextureRegion.split(new Texture("spritesheet.png"), 677, 1503)[0];
```

To get my `TextureRegion` array, and to start my animation:

```
animation = new Animation(1/12f, reg);
```

To render it, I do:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
batch.end();
```

However, this just renders a black box.

Although, when I change my `spritesheet.png` file to only have 6 frames side by side, the animation works fine, and my sprite is shown.

How do I animate my sprite properly with more than 6 frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably exceeding the maximum supported texture size for the device you're running on. If you intend to support Android, your Texture dimensions shouldn't be bigger than 2048 to support the vast majority of devices. For desktop, I think 4096 is safe.

Answer (score 0):

If Tenfour04 gave you the correct answer then you might want to look into `texturepacker`, it comes along with LibGDX and you can find it in the tools. It has a GUI and can be used from the command line as well. You do need to split up the individual images manually if you don't have them separate already.

Texturepacker will pack you individual sprites for you and you can setup options and constraints on how to pack them. It will also provide you with a atlas so you do not have to `.split` your sheets manually. All you need to do is load all the frames from the `TextureAtlas` in a array like you currently do and render from that.

Comment: no, it's fine. I made my images smaller, and lined them up side to side and top to bottom

Comment: @programmers5 Sure, but if you want to save time in the future I recommend it.